# v-if inside v-for is giving me Property or method "*" is not defined on the instance

Tags: vue.js

I want to be able to compare two dates in vue and add a class to the div if the date is less then the today date. This is my code:

```
<tr v-for="car in cars">
   <div v-if="Date.now() <= new Date(car.ContractDate)">if true, add class to this div</div>
</tr>
```

But I am getting this error instead:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "car" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

When i try to execute `<td>{{ car.ContractDate }}</td>` inside my `v-for` i don't have any issues.

Comment: Your issue may be because the v-if is running before the data is received. Maybe try using a computed property to determine the condition. Or you could try `v-if="cars.length >= 1 && YOUR_DATE_COMPARISON"`

Comment: nope, I am getting the same result I have pasted my whole code here if that helps: https://pastebin.com/MmBcp0Bx

Comment: you could try using a method to determine the v-if. here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6x892wL3/). methods will allow you to pass in the date of the car object which you can then check and return true of false for the v-if. and @DerekPollards example should work as well if you are wanting to bind a class to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a rough example based on the information you gave:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      cars: [{
        name: 'Car X',
        contractDate: '9/17/2016, 1:21:34 PM'
      },
      {
        name: 'Car Y',
        contractDate: '9/17/2020, 1:21:34 PM'
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    compareDate(d) {
      return (new Date(d)).getTime() > (new Date()).getTime();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="car in cars">
        <td>{{car.name}}</td>
        <td>
          <div :class="{ active: compareDate(car.contractDate) }">
            {{car.contractDate}}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### Notes

Instead of doing the comparison in the actual template, I elected to do it in a method - it felt cleaner

I'm using [object syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) for the class bind, again, purely preference, you could use a ternary if you so chose to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am still getting the same error :( Can you check my whole code here: https://pastebin.com/MmBcp0Bx

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code : https://pastebin.com/MmBcp0Bx

you should remove this line:

```
<div v-if="Date.now() <= new Date(car.ContractDate)">if true, add class to this div</div>
```